# What is the path for JDK on Windows 8 64-bit?

Tags: windows-8.1

When I work with the windows-cmd, it says that java-version is not recognized as an internal or external command. What shall I do? What is the path for jdk12.0.1?     what is the original path for win8.1 64-bit？

Comment: It's `java -version`, not `java-version`

Answer (score 0):

It's

```
java -version
```

not `java-version`. `-version` is an argument to `java` which is the main executable.